# Python - Batch rename to timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm pretty new to Python and i tried writing a code that takes a list of files (1.pdf,2.pdf,3.pdf etc') and renames it to the time it was created.

- I'm using Ubuntu 21 and python 3.8

  ```
    import time
    import os

    extension = ".pdf"
    folder_path = "/home/user/Downloads"
    file_list = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if filename.endswith(extension) and filename not in file_list:

            full = folder_path + '/' + filename
            t = os.path.getctime(full)

            t_str = time.ctime(t)

            t_obj = time.strptime(t_str)

            format_t = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S", t_obj)

            full_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            os.rename(full_path, os.path.join(folder_path, format_t + extension))
            name_sum = format_t + extension
            file_list.append(name_sum)
  ```

When i run the code files are deleted and only 1 file is left.
Please help me understand what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all renamed to the same name. You should add a check like:

```py
new_name = os.path.join(folder_path, format_t + extension)
if os.path.isfile(new_name):
    raise Exception(new_name + " exists already")
os.rename(full_path, new_name)
```

or handling files that were created at the exact same second by adding some suffix or something like that

Comment: First of all thanks, I tried adding that but the way i would want to handle this exception is by skipping this file until reaching the ones that weren't renamed

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You can use `continue` instead of the `Exception(...)` line if you want to skip the `rename` and you can use `break` if you want to end the loop

Comment: Can you accept the answer so as to close this post? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct and worked correctly on my system.

You could try adding an iterator counter number to differentiate the names in the loop. The uniqueness of the names may be caused of the "format_t" you add producing the same within the loop may be cause of the execution time or an internal bug within the time function yielding the same strings.

Comment: Worked fine? That's odd, after trying qmeeus's suggestion i get only some of the files to rename.